# Different ways of compiling a ocaml code with external libraries

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I have installed some libraries, and am trying to compile a code.

1) `ocamlc -I /usr/lib -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -c mlexample2.ml` generates well `mlexample2.cmi` and `mlexample2.cmo`

2) `ocamlopt -I /usr/lib -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -o mlexample2.opt` generates well `mlexample2.cmx`

3) However, If I follow the native-code compilation of [this page](http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/0.9.10/mlapronidl/Introduction.html#compilation):
`ocamlopt -I /usr/lib -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -o mlexample2.opt \ bigarray.cmxa gmp.cmxa apron.cmxa boxMPFR.cmxa polkaMPQ.cmxa mlexample2.ml` returns `File "mlexample2.ml", line 1, characters 0-1: Error: Cannot find file  bigarray.cmxa`, where `usr/lib` represents `$APRON/lib` in the doc. But `big.array.cmxa` is effectively in `/usr/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa`. By the way, this command does generate `.cmi`, `.cmx` and `.o`.

So my questions are:

How could I progress from `.cmi` and `.cmo` of 1)?

How could I progress from `.cmx` of 2)

What can I do with the error in 3)

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

**Edit1:** 2) should be: `ocamlopt -I /usr/lib -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -c mlexample2.ml` generates `.cmi`, `.cmx` and `.o`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other questions, it seems like you got some sample lines to compile and just blindly walking though without understanding the compile options.

1) You're compile line has the `-c` option. This option does not link, thus it allows someone to compile an individual module and link them later. This is helpful to allow the project to be built in pieces and updated in pieces for quicker final compilation. So, the `-c` option passed to [ocamlc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual022.html) produces your `cmi` and `cmo`, byte-code complied module.

2) You are missing something here in your sample compile line --it doesn't mention anything regarding to produce an additional file. I'm going to assume that you also use the `-c` option. This is because a `.cmx` is also a compiled module, but natively compiled via [ocamlopt](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html).

3) This should be a pretty obvious compilation error to fix. Where in your included directories does `bigarry.cmxa` reside? None of them. You've said it yourself that it is in `/usr/lib/ocaml/`, a directory you did not include! The directories *do not* search recursively, and you've experienced that before in other questions.

I strongly suggest you read the manual on compilation. This documentation you're wading through is correct in how to compile, but you've set your environment up in a different way and discerning the differences is going to be frustrating until you get a handle on what those commands are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... for 3) I have tried `ocamlopt -I /usr/lib/ocaml -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -o mlexample2.opt \ bigarray.cmxa gmp.cmxa apron.cmxa boxMPFR.cmxa polkaMPQ.cmxa mlexample2.ml
`, but the error still remains...

Comment: what is the output of `ocamlopt -where`?

Comment: you can always add the absolute path to `bigarray.cmxa` as well, but since it's in the standard library, you shouldn't need to add the additional path, `ocaml bigarray.cma` should load the toplevel with the Bigarray module. Does that work?

Comment: `ocamlopt -where` returns `/usr/lib/ocaml`

Comment: I tried `ocamlopt -I /usr/lib/ocaml -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp -o mlexample2.opt \ /usr/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa gmp.cmxa apron.cmxa boxMPFR.cmxa polkaMPQ.cmxa mlexample2.ml`, it still returns `File "mlexample2.ml", line 1, characters 0-1: Error: Cannot find file  /usr/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa`, however, `/usr/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa` does exist...

Comment: How can I check if `ocaml bigarray.cma` load the toplevel with the Bigarray module or not?

Comment: It will tell you if it cannot load the file, but type a command from the bigarray module; `Bigarray.Array2.of_array` for example, you'll get the function definition.

Comment: `Bigarray.Array2.of_array` does return the definition, that shows `ocaml bigarrray.cma` does what it is supposed to do. So it is really strange that the long command `ocamlopt ...` still does not work...

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem... I stupidly left `\` in the command, which should not be there... Thank you!

Comment: It really is supposed to show that the file is in the path that ocaml knows, and it is unnecessary to include it yourself. glad it worked out; weird/uninformative error for having a ` though.